# Download files from the web server by java

Tags: java

1. I would like to download the temp files from an web server
2. The code i tried is below, but i am getting only the HTML content being written the ouput file
3. But the url path contains 712 files in .gz format

This is the code I am using:

```
import java.io.*;

public class SampleFile{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new java.net.URL("http://xxx:9080/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.jsp?file=/apps/WasApps/xxx/templogs/xxx.log.xxx_Server1.2012-04-01.gz").openStream());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("LocalPath\\koushik.txt");
        BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos,1024);

        int x=0;
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        while((x=in.read(data,0,1024))>=0) {
            bout.write(data,0,x);
        }

        bout.close();
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Plop that URL down in a browser and see what response you get. I doubt it will be what you expect. Also, please format your code when posting to an online forum, you will be surprised how many more responses you get.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "the url path contains 712 files in .gz format" means?

Comment: Thanks for the response...My problem is now solved, What i tried is, i just opened the file to be downloaded in the server in a readable text format and used that url in the browser to download,it got downloaded fine.